# Prevent DOMDocument for escaping html

Tags: php, encoding, escaping, domdocument

I have a problem with DOMDocument, when I do a saveHTML () it returns my HTML code but with escaped elements in the case of invalid parameter (I use variables that I replace)

```
<h2><a href="$google_link">Link</a></h2>
```

**Become**

```
<h2><a href="%24google_link">Link</a></h2>
```

My code:

```php
<?php

$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
@$dom->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
            
// my code

$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';

$text = html_entity_decode($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo $text;
```

Comment: I tried with saveXML, it works but add tags and some others elements like CDATA and others: /

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace the links before parsing the HTML. Or use another format to set variables (ex: `variable://google_link`)

But, with the given data, you could use `urldecode()`:

```
$text = '<h2><a href="$google_link">Link</a></h2>';
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$text = $dom->saveHTML();

echo urldecode($text);
// <h2><a href="$google_link">Link</a></h2>
```